# New columns added to datatable are not showing up in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, tabcontrol

I have created a datatable then manually added two new columns in position 0 and 1, and given them default values. When I loop through the datatable it prints all the values out correctly and everything seems to be there. but when I pass the datatable to a DataGridView via a binding source it doesn't show the two new columns in the datagridview. Any idea as to what im doing wrong?

Regards

Amarino

```
DataTable lDT2 = Conn.ExecuteStoredProcedureValidation(lDT);

DataColumn newColumn1 = new DataColumn("TestName", typeof(string));
DataColumn newColumn2 = new DataColumn("SheetName", typeof(string));

newColumn1.DefaultValue = "test";
newColumn2.DefaultValue = "test2";

lDT2.Columns.Add(newColumn2);
lDT2.Columns.Add(newColumn1);

lDT2.Columns["TestName"].SetOrdinal(0);
lDT2.Columns["SheetName"].SetOrdinal(1);

DataGridView lDGV = new DataGridView();
lDGV.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing;
lDGV.RowHeadersVisible = false;

BindingSource BindingSource1 = new BindingSource(); //create new data binding source
BindingSource1.DataSource = lDT2;             //SetData source change to LDT2 
lDGV.DataSource = BindingSource1;
lDGV.RowHeadersVisible = true;

lDGV.Tag = page.Controls[0].Tag;
lDGV.AccessibleName = page.Controls[0].AccessibleName;

lFormV.tabControl_Val.TabPages[page.Name].Show();
lFormV.tabControl_Val.TabPages[page.Name].Controls.Add(lDGV);
```

Comment: What does it show?

Comment: just the content of the original datatable before I added the two new columns. I think it has to do with the type of table returned from the stored procedure im using.

Comment: What original datatable? Did you add one at design time? Are you showing multiple grids in the spot on the form, hiding one under another? If you already have a grid then set it's binding source, don't create a new one and add it to the form.

Comment: lDT2 is the datatable that gets created by an SQL server stored procedure. I create a datagridview dynamically. I create a new bindingsource, to which I assign the lDT2. I then set the datagridview datasource to the bindingsource. The datagridview then gets added to the tabcontrol. Everything is created dynamically at runtime apart from the tab control.